# Laravel how to remove Dots in eloquent where?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hi guyes in my sql database all numbers are saved in this format

100.000, 1.000, 10.000.000

I now have to do a filter like this:

```
Products::where('price','>',30000)->get()
```

Is there a way to remove dots directly in my eloquent select?

Comment: Why not store the data properly? Numbers should not contain any dots

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `whereRaw` and call a MySQL function to remove the dots, something like:

`Products::whereRaw("REPLACE(price, '.', '') > 3000")->get()`

For more info:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str_replace()` to replace dots to empty like this `str_replace(".", "", '10.000.000')`

```
Products::where('price','>',str_replace(".", "", '10.000.000'))->get();
```